# Ordenar de menor a mayor una lista

Tags: python, lista, pycharm

Tengo este código y deseo ordenar de menor a mayor de acuerdo al tamaño del diametro pero me sale TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'

```
mercurio = {"planeta": "mercurio ", "diametro": 4.878}
venus = {"planeta": "venus", "diametro": 12.104}
tierra = {"planeta": "tierra", "diametro": 12.756}
marte = {"planeta": "marte ", "diametro": 6.794}
jupiter = {"planeta": "jupiter", "diametro": 142.800}
saturno = {"planeta": "saturno", "diametro": 120.660}
urano = {"planeta": "urano", "diametro": 51.800}
neptuno = {"planeta": "neptuno", "diametro": 49.500}

lista = []
lista.extend([mercurio, venus, tierra, marte, jupiter, urano, neptuno])

for planeta in lista:
    print(planeta)


def ordenar(lista):
    for i in range(len(lista)):
        h = i
        while h > 0 and lista[h] < lista[h - 1]:
            aux = lista[h]
            lista[h] = lista[h - 1]
            lista[h - 1] = aux
            h = h - 1
            print(lista)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te comparto el código que te ayuda a mostrarlos de manera ordenada, y posteriormente te explico cómo funciona.

```
mercurio = {"planeta": "mercurio ", "diametro": 4.878}
venus = {"planeta": "venus", "diametro": 12.104}
tierra = {"planeta": "tierra", "diametro": 12.756}
marte = {"planeta": "marte ", "diametro": 6.794}
jupiter = {"planeta": "jupiter", "diametro": 142.800}
saturno = {"planeta": "saturno", "diametro": 120.660}
urano = {"planeta": "urano", "diametro": 51.800}
neptuno = {"planeta": "neptuno", "diametro": 49.500}

lista = []
lista.extend([mercurio, venus, tierra, marte, jupiter, urano, neptuno])

l = []
for planet in lista:
    l.append((planet["diametro"], planet["planeta"], ))

l.sort()
for planet in l:
    print("Planeta: ", planet[1], "\tDiametro: ", planet[0])
```

El resultado obtenido:

```
Planeta:  mercurio      Diametro:  4.878
Planeta:  marte         Diametro:  6.794
Planeta:  venus         Diametro:  12.104
Planeta:  tierra        Diametro:  12.756
Planeta:  neptuno       Diametro:  49.5
Planeta:  urano         Diametro:  51.8
Planeta:  jupiter       Diametro:  142.8
```

### Explicación

Básicamente lo que hice fue hacer una lista de tuplas donde incluía cada planeta y su respectivo diámetro, esto lo hice ya que las tuplas son comparables (por lo tanto se pueden ordenar) y los diccionarios no lo son. Después de hacer la lista de tuplas `l` solo las ordene con `l.sort()`, posteriormente solo imprimí.

Comment: Por favor, revisa tu resultado. No veo ningún orden en la lista producida.

Comment: Arreglado. Un error de dedo. Había copiado el orden original en vez del orden final

Answer (score 0):

respondiendo solo a tu pregunta de obtener el valor de menor o mayor puedes usar el método sort creando una nueva lista de diámetros.

```
mercurio = {"planeta": "mercurio ", "diametro": 4.878}
venus = {"planeta": "venus", "diametro": 12.104}
tierra = {"planeta": "tierra", "diametro": 12.756}
marte = {"planeta": "marte ", "diametro": 6.794}
jupiter = {"planeta": "jupiter", "diametro": 142.800}
saturno = {"planeta": "saturno", "diametro": 120.660}
urano = {"planeta": "urano", "diametro": 51.800}
neptuno = {"planeta": "neptuno", "diametro": 49.500}

lista = []
lista.extend([mercurio, venus, tierra, marte, jupiter, saturno, urano, neptuno])

diametros = []
for planeta in lista:
  diametros.append(planeta['diametro'])
diametros.sort()

print (diametros)
```

**Edición**

Resultado:

```
[4.878, 6.794, 12.104, 12.756, 49.5, 51.8, 120.66, 142.8]
```

Comment: Faltan los nombres de los planetas.

Comment: No veo el motivo por el cual deba poner puntos negativos a mi  respuesta ya que usted solo pregunta por el diámetro, sea prudente y aprenda a realizar las preguntas debidamente estructuradas. Lo cito ..."Tengo este código y deseo ordenar de menor a mayor de acuerdo al tamaño del diámetro"

Comment: Aprende a lidiar con usuarios. Tienes que leerles el pensamiento y anticiparte a sus necesidades. El puro diámetro no sirve para nada; es sólo un número sin conexión con ningún planeta en particular.

Comment: @Incorrecto, esta respuesta responde a la pregunta. *Tienes que leerles el pensamiento y anticiparte a sus necesidades.*, simplemente ridículo.